# how do i get the sum of the field values of array of objects in standardSQL BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

```
[
  {
    "ItemId": "001",
    "quantity": 2,
  },
    {
    "ItemId": "002",
    "quantity": 1,
  },
    {
    "ItemId": "003",
    "quantity": 10,
  },
    {
    "ItemId": "004",
    "quantity": 3,
  },

]
```

If i have a column containg array  like this, and if i want to sum the quantity and in this case the sum would be quantity=16

Answer (score 0):

Two options, depending on what you need. If you want to get the sum for each array:

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(quantity) FROM UNNEST(array_column))
FROM dataset.table
```

If you want to get the sum across all arrays:

```
SELECT SUM(quantity)
FROM dataset.table,
  UNNEST(array_column)
```